# tilt shift image processing effect

Tags: android, image-processing, graphics

I'm working on certain image processing project.

I need to implement tilt shift effect like Instagram one. I have already implemented basic effects like sepia, grayscale, various color effects and rotation using android.graphics package (Bitmap, Canvas, Paint).

I have found some code for blurring whole the image, but I do not know how to define circle that will be focused and the complement area that will be blurred.

How can I implement it using android.graphics or some other third party framework?
Is there some literature about the subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a tilt shift that used a circle for blur/focus, normally that would just be called selective focus. Tilt shift is normally blurred along a vertical gradient. To do that, you just need to multiply the strength of the blur by

`pixelY / height` for bottom blur

`(height - pixelY) / height` for top blur

or manipulate the basic formula for more control, eg:

`Math.abs(pixelY - (height / 2)) / (height / 2)` for center focus with top/bottom blur

That's assuming your blur code has a strength variable. If it doesn't, it should.

There's also typically contrast/saturation adjustments, but it seems you can do that part already since you listed color effects.

For a good tutorial that covers what adjustments to make for a tilt-shift effect see [this](http://www.tiltshiftphotography.net/tilt-shift-photography-photoshop-tutorial/#.UIGtJSGRyiI). It's a Photoshop tutorial, but you can see what steps they take.

Comment: hi i also need to use the focuse concept with help of tilt shift please give any sample.help me please

Comment: have any code example in java for better understanding point of view.